# Is it permissible to use safety pins to hold ihram together while doing umrah?

Tags: hajj, umrah

And what about belt to hold money.

I've come across conflicting answers, on this site, through phone calls and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When doing my haj the Malaysian authorities gave us big saftey pins to keep our top ihram from falling off. So yes you can use them.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just safety pins or belt you can use to keep your ihram izaar up? Some use nothing - pretty confident just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have a safety pin to hold your **"Ahram"** or **"Ihram"**. But when i was going for Umrah, i bought a book. It was written that you cannot use stitched cloth to cover your body or on your body. Safety pins and the belt to keep safe your personal belongings are good to have so no problem in have that.